# Cannot put $url; on "define" PHP

Tags: php

Im newbie in php im learning it since some weeks ago but i didnt understand one thing.
I have a

```
$url = "http://example.com/";
define('LOCATION', '<?php echo $url; ?>');
```

but it is not working. I didnt understand why "define" term cannot read

Comment: Please review your question as if you are a stranger to your situation. Please specify: What you are trying to do, what your problem is, what you have tried, how we should help you. Otherwise, you will receive no answer. :(

Comment: Why assign the same string twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = "http://example.com/";
define('LOCATION',  $url);
```

1.You are alreay in php tag,so no need of any extra php tag.

2.And when assigning value to a variable , we never use echo in php . Its used to display value in html only.

Comment: OMG im ashamed! I didnt saw it :O maybe I need a little bit of coffee, thank you :) sorry for stpd question...

Comment: No issue , you can upvote and accept as an answer . Thanks

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Correct answer. Just a tip: you should not use closing php tags (`?>`). They cause many many troubles and actually offer no advantage at all. Just remove them from _all_ your php files and you have a whole lot of issues less.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com That was pretty fast, if you really removed them from all your php files ;-)

Comment: @arkascha I am talking about answer :)